# Basic network connectivity report (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking

I need a Windows program that a user with no technical background can run to see a few basic facts about his network connectivity: Is the PC connected to any network? If yes: Can we ping the default gateway? Can we resolve hosts to IPs? Can we ping some well known Internet host (e.g. www.google.com)? How stable pings to the default gateway and to a well known Internet host are over a small period of time?

A portable version would be nice to have.